# How do you pass an array of structs to a C API?

Tags: c, swift, ffi

I have a C API which looks like this:

```c
typedef struct Datapoints {
  double *ptr;
  uintptr_t len;
} Datapoints;

double my_function(const struct Datapoints *baseline_data,
                     uint32_t baseline_data_len,
                     const struct Datapoints *new_data);
```

and I'm finding it difficult to call this from Swift. The first argument is an array of pointers to `Datapoints` structs and the third arg is a single `Datapoints` struct.

This is what I've come up with, but it won't work for several reasons, the main one being that I'm trying to store up a list of unsafe pointers to later pass them in to `my_function`. I've obfuscated the code a bit by renaming variables and types, so please forgive me if it doesn't compile. The code basically looks like this:

```swift
var baseline_datapoints = [Datapoints]()
var current_datapoints:Datapoints = Datapoints()

// This loop was intended to build up an array `baseline_Datapoints` containing pointers to struct `Datapoints`
for reading in baseline {
    let datapoints:[Double] = reading.datapoints

    // Won't work: The pointer passed as an argument to `body` is valid only during the
    // execution of `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(_:)`. Do not store or return
    // the pointer for later use.
    // We _are_ attempting to store it for later use. 

    datapoints.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer{ ptr in
        baseline_datapoints.append(Datapoints(ptr: ptr.baseAddress, len: UInt(datapoints.count)) )
    }
}

self.newData.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {ptr in
    current_datapoints = Datapoints(ptr: ptr.baseAddress, len: UInt(self.newData.count))
}

let x = baseline_datapoints.withUnsafeBufferPointer{
    (baselineptr: UnsafeBufferPointer<Datapoints>) -> Double in
    return withUnsafePointer(to: current_datapoints) {
        (current_ptr: UnsafePointer<Datapoints>) -> Double in

        return my_function(baseline_ptr.baseAddress, UInt32(baseline_datapoints.count ), current_ptr)
    }
}
```

I *think* what I should be doing is to extend the scope of the `withUnsafeXxxPointer` closures so the data remains valid long enough. However, I'm not sure how I'd do that when trying to build up the `baseline_data` list.

Also, it seems inconvenient to use one closure for each unsafe pointer. If I do it that way it will cause the code to nest deeply.  Is there some other way to do this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:

The accepted answer worked perfectly, except that the third parameter was being passed by value.  However, this turned out to be a better design for the C API anyway, so I changed my API to this:

```
double my_function(const struct Datapoints *baseline_data,
                     uint32_t baseline_data_len,
                     const struct Datapoints new_data);
```

Both `baseline_data` and `new_data` are in parameters, for the record.

Comment: When you describe a C API like this, it’s not sufficient to just mention the argument and return types. You also need to specify the memory management convention followed by the function, which can’t be expressed by the API (it’s usually described in the header documentation, or in a naming op convention like with the “copy rule” and “get rule” in CoreFoundarion). Without that, we can’t know what’s the right way to pass values from Swift

Comment: Based on my reading of the sample code provided, it looks like new_data is the "out" parameter (the double values it points to will be modified) and baseline_data is an "input". But this is an assumption since it's not specified in the question.

Comment: Yes, good points @Alexander, they are in fact _both_ input parameters.  In fact I have since changed the function signature such that `new_data` is now passed by value.  You are correct that it was ambiguous.

Comment: You also need to specify what the function does with these inputs. Does it use them right away, or stash them away later to use elsewhere? These determines whether a temporary pointer is sufficient, or if you need to do something more special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate reality is that it's unsafe in Swift to store and reuse the value of `ptr.baseAddress` outside the closure passed to `datapoints.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`. This is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/withunsafemutablebufferpointer(_:)):

> … The pointer argument is valid only for the duration of the method’s execution.

This means there's no way to do what you're trying to do in the `for` loop*, and the same applies to the way you're letting the `baseAddress` escape from `self.newData.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { }`.

The cleanest, safest solution is going to require actually *copying* the underlying Doubles. This would look more like:

```swift
var baseline_bufs = [UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>]()
defer {
  // don't forget to deallocate memory that was allocated!
  for d in baseline_bufs {
    d.deallocate()
  }
}

// Copy data from baseline readings into UnsafeMutableBufferPointers
for reading in baseline {
  d = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: reading.datapoints.count)
  d.initialize(from: reading.datapoints)
  baseline_bufs.append(d)
}


let x = self.newData.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { newDataBuf in
  let new_ptr = Datapoints(ptr: newDataBuf.baseAddress, len: UInt(newDataBuf.count))

  // convert each `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` to a `Datapoints`
  let baseline_datapoints = baseline_bufs.map { Datapoints(ptr: $0.baseAddress, len: UInt($0.count)) }
  return baseline_datapoints.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    return my_function($0.baseAddress, UInt32($0.count), new_ptr)
  }
}
```

*Maybe there's *some* way to get all the withUnsafeX calls to be nested using recursion, but you'd run into stack size limits depending on the number of items in the array.

Comment: Yeah, you either need to use an UnsafeBufferPointer from the start, or stick with Array and copy in and copy out as necessary. The former is more performant (if that matters), while the latter is easier and safer

Comment: If OP's original source data is in an Array of Arrays, I don't think there's any safe way to avoid copying unless the code can be refactored to not use Arrays at all. (Basically, this is what UnsafeMutableBufferPointer was designed for.) Since the API takes an UnsafePointer to an array of structs holding UnsafePointers, I opted to use explicit UnsafeMutableBufferPointers for the inner ones, and an Array + .withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer for the outer one.

Comment: Copying huh?  I _thought_ it might come to that.  Thanks for the thorough answer.  I'll try it shortly and let you know.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this approach works.  Thanks for your help.